# push JavaScript objects without using index as a key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through a set of data and create a list of JavaScript objects. The packet structure just looks like this

```
let packet = {
location: "",
email: "" 
}
```

Where the key for each packet should be the person's name. So preferably like so

```
let packet = {
 [name]:{
  location: "",
  email: "" 
 }
}
```

Then I loop through a set of data populating each packet and pushing it into a list of packets

```
let packets = [];
for(index = 0; index < data.length; ++index){
 let packet = {
 [getnamefromdata(data[index])]:{
  location: getlocationfromdata(data[index]),
  email: getemailfromdata(data[index])
 }
}
packets.push(packet);
}
```

getname,location,emailfromdata are just dummy pseudo functions.
But the issue I have here is, instead of the packet structure looking like a list of keys with the name as each key, instead its a list of integer indices which look like this

```
0:{
 keyname:{
  location:
  email:
 }
}
1:{
 keyname:{
  location:
  email:
 }
}
2:{
 keyname:{
  location:
  email:
 }
}
```

But I really dislike it this way. Is it possible to get rid of each index and use the key name instead because each key is going to be unique.
So I'd prefer it like this

```
keyname:{
 location:
 email:
}
keyname:{
 location:
 email:
}
keyname:{
 location:
 email:
}
```

Comment: what do the objects/data within `data` look like?

Comment: @NickParsons They look like this `0:{
 keyname:{
  location:""
  email:""
 }
}` where 0 is the index. And it does this for every index

Comment: Could you provide a sample data object here?

Comment: So the problem creating the indices was using push and treating it like an array, when I could have just treated it like an object with key pair values.

Comment: Rolled back your edit because there's no need to have the answer in the question. That's what the answers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an object with key/value pairs instead of array of packets.

```
const packets = {};

for(index = 0; index < data.length; ++index){
  packets[getnamefromdata(data[index])] = {
    location: getlocationfromdata(data[index]),
    email: getemailfromdata(data[index])
  };
}
```

You can also do this without the for loop and use `reduce` method.

```js
const packets = data.reduce((prev, current) => ({
  ...prev,
  [getnamefromdata(current)]: {
    location: getlocationfromdata(current),
    email: getemailfromdata(current)
  }
}), {});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Yes! That did it ! Thank you. Every answer I had previously looked at said to push data to add onto JSON objects, but your way is better, just assigning the data to each key.